# Inputed data becoming the new data in a for loop

Tags: python, loops, conditional-statements

Long story short, my buddy and I made a joke. Whenever the Washington football team beats a team, that team becomes "the football team". Week 1, the football team beat the Eagles so now they are known as the Philadelphia Football Team. I got carried away and I decided to make a python program that would do this.

```
for i in range(17):
    city = "Washington"
    football_team = city + " Football Team"
    answer = input("Did the " + football_team + " win today? ")
    if answer == "No":
        print("The team is the " + football_team)
    if answer == "Yes":
        city = input("Who did the " + football_team + " defeat? ")
        football_team = city + " Football Team"
        print("The new football team is the " + football_team)
```

Whenever the user inputs the answer yes and inputs a new city for the football team, the loop goes back to the top where:

```
city = "Washington"
```

I was hoping I could find a way once the code reiterates, the name of the city isn't Washington. I understand how this makes sense in the code, but I cannot put my finger on how I can get the city to change its name. If the user answers "Yes" and puts in a new football team name, the code works in the way that I desire until it reiterates. How can I get the new inputted data to be the now, original data for this code?

Comment: You could define the variable outside of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Define the variable "city" outside of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

There could be 2 solutions based on what you require. If the statements--"Whenever the Washington football team beats a team, that team becomes "the football team". Week 1, the football team beat the Eagles so now they are known as the Philadelphia Football Team"--holds true for the new team as well (if eagles beat someone Steelers then they are now known as Pittsburg Football team) then go for solution 1.
**Solution 1**

```
for i in range(5):
if i==0:
    city = "Washington"
football_team = city + " Football Team"
answer = input("Did the " + football_team + " win today? ")
if answer == "No":
    print("The team is the " + football_team)
if answer == "Yes":
    city = input("Who did the " + football_team + " defeat? ")
    football_team = city + " Football Team"
    print("The new football team is the " + football_team)
```

On the other hand if the criteria always has the be the Washington football team then go for solution 2.
**Solution 2:**

```
for i in range(5):
if i==0:
    city = "Washington"
football_team = city + " Football Team"
answer = input("Did the " + "Washington Football Team" + " win today? ")
if answer == "No":
    print("The team is the " + football_team)
if answer == "Yes":
    city = input("Who did the " + "Washington Football Team" + " defeat? ")
    football_team = city + " Football Team"
    print("The new football team is the " + football_team)
```

Comment: Solution 1 was the right one for me. Looking at the if statement using the i, it makes so much sense to me now! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As stated above, you need to initialize the `'Washington'` as the city, then can update based on who wins.

So this looked fun, I had a go at it as well to automate it by checking the scores:

```
import requests
import operator

def diffr(items):
    return items[0] - sum(items[1:])

football_team_dict = {'city':'Washington','team':'Football Team'}

for i in range(1,18):
    url = 'http://site.api.espn.com/apis/site/v2/sports/football/nfl/scoreboard?week=%s' %i
    jsonData = requests.get(url).json()['events']
    
    #Get Football Team game
    for game in jsonData:
        if football_team_dict['city'] in game['name']:
            break
        
    if game['status']['type']['completed'] == True:
        print('Week %s'%i)
        
        #Check if Football Team won
        score_dict = {}
        for team in game['competitions'][0]['competitors']:
            score_dict.update({team['team']['location']:int(team['score'])})
        winCity = max(score_dict.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]
        lossCity = min(score_dict.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]
        
        if diffr(list(score_dict.values())) == 0:
            print ('%s tied %s with the score of %s - %s.' %(game['competitions'][0]['competitors'][0]['team']['location'], game['competitions'][0]['competitors'][1]['team']['location'], score_dict[winCity], score_dict[lossCity]))
            winCity = football_team_dict['city']
        else:
            print ('%s defeated %s with the score of %s - %s.' %(winCity, lossCity, score_dict[winCity], score_dict[lossCity]))
        
        if winCity == football_team_dict['city']:
            print ('The football team is still the %s Football Team.\n' %football_team_dict['city'])
        else:
            football_team_dict.update({'city':winCity})
            print ('The new football team is the %s Football Team.\n' %football_team_dict['city'])
```

**Output:**

```
Week 1
Washington defeated Philadelphia with the score of 27 - 17.
The football team is still the Washington Football Team.

Week 2
Arizona defeated Washington with the score of 30 - 15.
The new football team is the Arizona Football Team.

Week 3
Detroit defeated Arizona with the score of 26 - 23.
The new football team is the Detroit Football Team.

Week 4
New Orleans defeated Detroit with the score of 35 - 29.
The new football team is the New Orleans Football Team.
```

Comment: Wow you really took this a lot farther than I did!